# JUJU Bootstrap Connection Error

Tags: juju, maas

UBUNTU 16.04

MAAS 2.0.0 beta 4

Juju 1.25.5

1) juju ,region and rack controller same server , Server1
Server1: eth0: 192.168.120.2 // MAAS egion and rack controller ip
Server1: eth1" 10.?.?.? // For internet connection

2) Server1 has 2 connection one local private 192.168.?.? and one connected to main network and internet 10.?.?.

3) Mass reghion and rack set at 192.168.120.2

4)after bootstrap it says can not connect to 192.168.120.2! juju tries to bootstrap on same server1 as MAAS?

Answer (score 2):

Juju does not support MAAS2 until 2.0.0 beta 7.

Comment: How can I install maas 1.9?

Comment: Dear Thumper, do you have any estimation about date of release for beta 7?

Comment: Imminent. We are just squashing the remaining few bugs, and hoping to get it out today or tomorrow.